# Symfony 2 Call a function(with temlate render) in a Controller

Tags: php, symfony

i have two simple functions inside my controller:

```
    public function indexAction(){

    $userid = $this->getUser()->getId();

    $userdata = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('LiveupUserBundle:userData')
            ->findOneById($userid);

    $userfriends = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('LiveupUserBundle:userFriends')
            ->findByUser($userid);
    return $this->render('LiveupMainBundle:Main:profile.html.twig', array(
        'userdata' => $userdata,
        'userfriends' => $userfriends
    ));
}
```

and

```
    public function peopleAction($nick){
    if($nick){

        $frienddata = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository('LiveupUserBundle:userData')
                ->findOneByNick($nick);

        if($frienddata->getId() === $this->getUser()->getId())
        {
            self::indexAction();
        }else{
            $friendfriends = $this->getDoctrine()
                    ->getRepository('LiveupUserBundle:userFriends')
                    ->findByUser($frienddata->getId());

            return $this->render('LiveupMainBundle:Main:people_profile.html.twig', array(
                'frienddata' => $frienddata,
                'friendfriends' => $friendfriends
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is when if statement in second function is true, I want to execute indexAction and render template from that function(profile.html.twig) but I get no response error. Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [forwarding a request](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#forwarding).  From the docs, you can do something like this:

```
public function peopleAction($nick){
    if($nick){

        $frienddata = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('LiveupUserBundle:userData')
            ->findOneByNick($nick);

        if($frienddata->getId() === $this->getUser()->getId())
        {
            $response = $this->forward('AppBundle:Something:index', array(
                 'var1'  => $anyVar //if you need to forward a param
            ));
        }else{
            $friendfriends = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository('LiveupUserBundle:userFriends')
                ->findByUser($frienddata->getId());

            $response = $this->render('LiveupMainBundle:Main:people_profile.html.twig', array(
                'frienddata' => $frienddata,
                'friendfriends' => $friendfriends
            ));
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Also, by looking at your code, you will still get an error if your `$nick` variable evaluates to `false` because no response will be returned.  You should ensure that you are ALWAYS returning a response from a controller.

Another thing to think about, maybe redirecting will meet your needs as well.  look at [the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#redirecting) to see how to do that, it is pretty simple from a controller.

Comment: please, it the fact of having one `return` instead of two at the end of an your action is what is called 'refactoring' in programming? thanks for the solution anyway, very interesting

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `return` statement:

```
return self::indexAction();
```

Also if `nick` can be empty you should process this case and throw an exception or return Response.